# How can I inject code into PHP via vulnerable endpoint?

Tags: php, security, code-injection

I am trying myself on an 'easy' pentest box of HackTheBox. During my investigation I found an endpoint with a vulnerable variable `example.php?file=` that gets not sanitised.

Through path traversal I was able to retrieve `/etc/passwd` as well as the source code of `example.php` (payload `file=./../../../../../../var/www/html/example.php`) which is the following:

```
<?php
$file = $_GET['file'];
$fh = fopen("files/$file","r");
while ($line = fgets($fh)) {
  echo($line);
}
fclose($fh);
?>
```

Now I tried myself at injecting some addition PHP code into the example.php file but to no preveil. Given that what ever 'file' evaluates to gets put into fopen I tested the following payloads while trying to break out of the existing code:

1. `","r");exec("whoami", $output);print_r($output);//` get whoami returned in the response body, didn't work,, but gave a 200 response
2. `","r");exec("nc -l -p 8080 -e /bin/bash");//` setup netcat backdoor to send commands directly to a shell - didn't work

Can someone help me figure this one out? How can I successfuly perform some form of remote code injection here on this clearly vulnerable piece of code? Thank's in advance

Comment: You cannot have RCE with this vulnerable sample.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could briefly explain why. In XSS you can also try and break out of the context and perform RCE. Thx

Comment: Because unless there is `eval` in php (or something similar that runs arbitrary commands) - you cannot make any extra functions to run. You can just change the string contents.

Comment: "In XSS you can also try and break out" --- because XSS mutates source code. And here you don't mutate source code, you can only change the `$file` variable contents, and that's it.

Comment: Thank you for your elaboration. It makes sense. I somehow thought if I break out of the existing code it would automatically get embeded and executed.